# Why Facebook Auth API use GET method

Tags: security, facebook-graph-api, access-token, facebook-access-token

I was looking at Facebook APIs and what I noticed is that all the token params are passed through GET request, that is in clear, is that safe?

Examples I've found on the [official doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens?locale=en):

```
curl -i -X GET "https://graph.facebook.com/{api-endpoint}&access_token={your-app_id}|{your-app_secret}"   
curl -i -X GET "https://graph.facebook.com/{your-user-id}/accounts&access_token={user-access-token}"
```

As you can see both requests have params that should be kept hide on the path. So maybe they should be put on the body of a POST request.

EDIT: I know that over HTTPS both header and body are encrypted but the params on the path remain clear, so the question is: Why Facebook has decided to put the access token inside the path?

Comment: As long as you think passing anything via POST instead of GET would increase security in any way, shape or form, I’d say it is pointless even having this discussion. Please go inform yourself about some basics, if you are still at _that_ level …

Comment: Well, actually your comment isn't very helpful. Since I know that header and body are encrypted over HTTPS I think that a POST method is more secure than a GET passing all parameters on path. Am I right?

Comment: _“I think that a POST method is more secure than a GET passing all parameters on path. Am I right?”_ - No, you are not.

Answer (score 0):

My bad, I discovered that also query strings are encrypted over HTTPS